# How to remove a known last part from commands output string in one line?

Tags: bash, string-substitution, command-substitution

To rephrase - I want to use Bash command substitution and string substitution in the same line.

My actual commands are longer, but the ridiculous use of echo here is just a "substitution" for shortness and acts the same - with same errors ;)

I know we can use a Bash command to produce it's output string as a parameter for another command like this:

```
echo "$(echo "aahahah</ddd>")"
aahahah</ddd>
```

I also know we can remove last known part of a string like this:

```
var="aahahah</ddd>"; echo "${var%</ddd>}"
aahahah
```

I am trying to write a command where one command gives a string output, where I want to remove last part, which is known.

```
echo "${$(echo "aahahah</ddd>")%</ddd>}"
-bash: ${$(echo "aahahah</ddd>")%</ddd>}: bad substitution
```

It might be the order of things happening or substitution only works on variables or hardcoded strings. But I suspect just me missing something and it is possible.

How do I make it work?
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to combine a command substitution and a string substitution as you want.  If you are determined to use a one-liner then you could use `sed` instead of string substitution: `echo "$(echo 'aahahah</ddd>' | sed 's:</ddd>$::')"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a dollar sign as in `$word` or equivalently `${word}` is used, it asks for `word`'s content. This is called parameter expansion, as per `man bash`.

You may write `var="aahahah</ddd>"; echo "${var%</ddd>}"`: That expands `var` and performs a special suffix operation before returning the value.

However, you may not write `echo "${$(echo "aahahah</ddd>")%</ddd>}"` because there is nothing to expand once `$(echo "aahahah</ddd>")` is evaluated.

From `man bash` (my emphasis):

> ${parameter%word}
>
> Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a 
>   pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern
>   matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then 
>   the result of the expansion is **the expanded value of parameter** 
>   with  the shortest  matching pattern (the ''%'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the ''%%'' case) deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Combine your commands like this

```
var=$(echo "aahahah</ddd>")
echo ${var/'</ddd>'}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that works, replacement of variable contents with nothing, but seems to me like giving up the oneliner dream :D